# Why is the determinant continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Why is the determinant as a function from $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{R}$ continuous? Can anyone explain precisely and rigorously? So far, I know the explanation which comes from the facts that

- polynomials are continuous,
- sum and product of continuous functions are continuous.

Also I have the confusion regarding the metric on $M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Isn't it clear that polynomials are continuous functions? $M_n(\mathbb R)$ is the same as $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ under a different disguise.

Comment: Non-rigorous, but perhaps helpful.... Determinants can be show to be equivalent to the hyper-volume of a hyper-parallelepiped with all the edges extending from one vertex defined by the columns (or rows) of a matrix.  Given that this volume changes continuously with a change in any component vector, the determinant may be seen to be continuous.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

$M_n(\mathbb R)$ is just $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ with the euclidian metric.

determinant is continuous, because it is a polynomial in the coordinates
$$
\det(X) = \det ([x_{i,j}])= \sum_\sigma \text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^{n} x_{\sigma(i),i},
$$
where $\sigma:\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ is a permutation.

Comment: It should be noted that $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is often also given the metric induced by the operator norm. Of course the point is, it doesn't matter because all norms on a finite dimensional space induce the same topology.

Comment: I do not understand your expression at the right side of the inequality.also what do you mean by $\det (x_{i,j})$?

Comment: Is this argument independent of the metric you define on $M_n(\mathbb{R})$? (haven't taken topology yet)

Comment: @ChrisJing all norms induce the same topology

Answer (score 48):

Recall that the determinant can be computed by a sum of determinants of minors, that is "sub"-matrices of smaller dimension.

Now we can prove by induction that $\det$ is continuous:

- For $n=1$, $A\in M_1(\mathbb R)$ is simply a scalar we have that $\det A=A$, and surely the identity function is continuous.
- Suppose that for $n$ we have that $\det$ is continuous on $M_n(\mathbb R)$, let $A\in M_{n+1}(\mathbb R)$. We know that $\det A$ can be calculated as the alternating sum over one of first row, when calculating the $\det$ of the appropriate minor.

  So $\det A$ is written as a sum and scalar multiplication of $\det$ on a smaller dimension. From the induction hypothesis these are continuous and therefore $\det$ is continuous on $n+1\times n+1$ matrices.

Answer (score 13):

The coefficient maps $A\longmapsto a_{i,j}$ are continuous because they are linear on the finite-dimensional vector space $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Here you want to refer to the topology of the latter as a normed space, which does not depend on the norm since they are all equivalent in finite dimension. Then the determinant is a polynomial in the coefficients, so it is continuous by composition of continuous maps.

Answer (score 8):

This answer is for $\epsilon-\delta$ fans!

Consider determinant as a function of the form $\det: \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$. What are the elements of its domain? Indeed, they are functions! More specifically, if $A\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ then $A$ is a function of the form $A:\{1,\dots,n\}\times\{1,\dots,n\} \to \mathbb{R}$ which we usually call a matrix. Furthermore, the domain and target space of $\det$, i.e. $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R}$, are *finite* dimensional normed vector spaces. To investigate the continuity of $\det$, we have to choose norms on $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R}$. However, these normed spaces are finite dimensional and it does not really matter what type of norm we choose as they are all equivalent in such spaces. Consequently, we shall choose the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) $\lVert\cdot\rVert_F$ on $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and absolute value $|\cdot|$ on $\mathbb{R}$ for further investigation. Then, continuity of determinant at $A \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ reads as

\begin{equation}
\forall\epsilon>0, \quad \exists\delta>0, \quad \lVert B-A \rVert_F < \delta \implies |\det B - \det A| <\epsilon.
\end{equation}

The hard work is to obtain an upper bound for $|\det B - \det A|$ in terms of $\lVert B-A \rVert_F$. Fortunately, this can be done.

> **Lemma**. Let $A, B \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$. If $\lVert B-A \rVert_F \leq 1$ then we have
> \begin{equation}
> |\det B - \det A|\leq M \,\lVert B-A \rVert_F,
> \end{equation}
> where $M = n!\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\,C_m^n \lVert A\rVert^{m}_F$ and $C_m^n$ is $n$ choose $m$.

Continuity of determinant follows imidiately from this lemma. More specifically, given any $\epsilon > 0$, some $0 < \delta \leq \min\{1, \frac{\epsilon}{M}\}$ would work.

**Remark 1**. There is an extension of the above lemma for multi-linear forms on normed vector spaces. Determinant can be considered as an n-linear form on the normed vector space $\mathbb{R}^n\times\dots\times\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Remark 2**. Note that the constant $M$ depends on $A$ so that determinant is not uniformly continuous. Indeed, this is the case for multi-linear forms on normed vector spaces.

**Proof**. Firstly, pay attention to some definitions and notation. We know that

\begin{equation}
\det A = \sum_{\sigma\in \mathcal{S}_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma) A_{\sigma(1),1}\dots A_{\sigma(n),n},
\end{equation}
where $\sigma:\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ is a permutation of $(1,\dots,n)$ and $\mathcal{S}_n$ is the set of all permutations. Also, let $H:=B-A$ be the change in $A$ and define the following index set
\begin{equation} 
I_m:=\{ (i_1,\dots,i_n)\,|\,i_j\in\{0, 1\},\,i_1+\dots+i_n=m \}.
\end{equation}
This is no magic and will show up in finding the upper bound naturally but I just wanted to make the definition before getting into that. Now, let us dive into it.

\begin{align}
|\det B - \det A| &= 
\Big|\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_n}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\big(B_{\sigma(1),1} \dots B_{\sigma(n),n} - A_{\sigma(1),1} \dots A_{\sigma(n),n}\big)\Big| \\
&\leq \sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_n}\big|\text{sgn}(\sigma)\big|\big|B_{\sigma(1),1} \dots B_{\sigma(n),n} - A_{\sigma(1),1} \dots A_{\sigma(n),n}\big| \\
&= \sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_n}\big|(A_{\sigma(1),1}+H_{\sigma(1),1}) \dots (A_{\sigma(n),n}+H_{\sigma(n),n}) - A_{\sigma(1),1} \dots A_{\sigma(n),n}\big| \\
&= \sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_n}\Big|\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i\in I_m}\big(H_{\sigma(1), 1}^{1-i_1}A_{\sigma(1),1}^{i_1}\big)\dots\big(H_{\sigma(n), n}^{1-i_n}A_{\sigma(n),n}^{i_n}\big)\Big| \\
&\leq \sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_n}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i\in I_m}\big|H_{\sigma(1), 1}^{1-i_1}\dots H_{\sigma(n),n}^{1-i_n}\big|\big|A_{\sigma(1), 1}^{i_1}\dots A_{\sigma(n),n}^{i_n}\big| \\
&\leq \sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_n}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i\in I_m} \lVert H\rVert^{n-(i_1+\dots+i_n)}_F \lVert A\rVert^{i_1+\dots+i_n}_F \\
&= \sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_n}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}|I_m|\lVert H\rVert^{n-m}_F \lVert A\rVert^{m}_F \\
&= \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} |\mathcal{S}_n| \,C_m^n \lVert H\rVert^{n-m}_F \lVert A\rVert^{m}_F \\
&=\lVert H \rVert_F \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} n!\,C_m^n \lVert H\rVert^{n-m-1}_F \lVert A\rVert^{m}_F \\
&\leq \lVert H \rVert_F \, \Big(n! \sum_{m=0}^{n-1}C_m^n \lVert A\rVert^{m}_F\Big),
\end{align}
where the last inequality holds provided that $\lVert H \rVert_F \leq 1$. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 2):

It's continuous because it's computable as a function from $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I'm curious if you can elaborate on why computable functions (in the relevant sense) are continuous?

Comment: @IsaacSolomon It's essentially the finite use principal. See [here](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2008/01/what-does-topology-have-to-do-with.html) for example.

Comment: @QuinnCulver If someone downvoted, it was probably because they thought the terminology was a little vague. I can see your idea (and this is how I think of it, too) is that the determinant is a composition of finitely many addition and multiplication operations, all of which are jointly continuous, and so the composition is continuous.

Comment: @rschwieb Actually the notion of a computable function on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a precisely defined one. See for example, *Computable Analysis* by Weihrauch.

Comment: @QuinnCulver Vague was the wrong word: I was thinking "obscure". I definitely have heard the term before via word of mouth, I have never had the opportunity to read it in print, so I'm betting others are the same way. What I described is the essential reason computable functions are continuous, no?

Comment: @rschwieb, Yes, that's fine. But you don't even have to think of it that way. Just knowing that co-factor expansion is an effective procedure allows for invocation of Church's thesis.

Comment: @QuinnCulver No objection here, since the veracity of your claim has never been in doubt: only the accessibility of it. It's good policy to assume others have not read everything you have.