# Connectedness in Matrices

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Are orthogonal matrices connected?? What about Unitary matrices and Normal matrices??
I would also like to know about the path connectedness in them(Need an explanation).

Comment: Since matrix groups are subsets of Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, path-connectedness is equivalent to connectedness. As for determining the connectivity of examples, there are two useful techniques: try to prove it is connected by constructing a path between any matrix and the identity, or try to prove it isn't using a continuous map onto a discontinuous space. The determinant map is very useful in many examples.

Comment: Connectedness and path-connectedness is equivalent for open sets only. If any of these methods works, though, we would either have a path-connected set (hence connected) or a disconnected set (hence not path-connected either).

Comment: @JonathanY.: Oh right, I should have said they are equivalent because matrix groups are manifolds. Also I have a typo disconnected=>discontinuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group of real orthogonal matrices is not connected, see here: [Topology of matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196195/topology-of-matrices). The unitary matrices are connected. The reason is that any unitary matrix can be diagonalized by a unitary matrix, and this gives a path from it to the identity. Indeed, every matrix Lie group is a smooth manifold, hence it is path-connected if and only if it is connected. The sum or product of two normal matrices is not necessarily normal, so it makes no sense to consider normal matrices here.