# Is the trace set of orthogonal matrix compact?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, compactness, trace, orthogonal-matrices

> Show that $$T = \{ \mbox{tr} (A) : A \in O_n (\mathbb{R}) \}$$ is compact.

I tried to show this set is compact. I could not. Any hint would suffice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The trace is equal to the sum of eigenvalues. What do you know about the eigenvalues of orthogonal matrices?

Comment: thanks. unit modulus. How to use this here?

Comment: There are $n$ eigenvalues, and they all have unit modulus. The sum of them therefore has to be between...?

Comment: The trace is continuous. The orthogonal group is compact.

Comment: @user1551 nice answer. can you please post this as answer, so that I can accept it? thanks.

Comment: @Arthur of modulus less than or equal to n? is this what you are saying or am i wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trace is a continuous function (this should be obvious). The orthogonal group is compact (one can easily check that it is closed and bounded). Since continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets, the result follows.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196195/topology-of-matrices) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447102/orthogonal-matrices-forms-a-compact-set).

Answer (score 4):

Consider the inner product $\langle A,B \rangle=tr(AB^t)$ in $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$. If $A$ is orthogonal then $AA^t=Id_{n}$ and $|tr(A)|=|tr(A Id_n)|\leq\sqrt{tr(AA^t)}\sqrt{tr(IdId^t)}=tr(Id)=n$.

Thus, your set $T$ is a subset of $[-n,n]$. Now, let's see tha $T=[-n,n]$.

If $n$ is even. Consider the following matrix in $O_n(\mathbb{R})$:

$A_n(\theta)= \begin{pmatrix}cos(\theta)&-sin(\theta)&0&0&\ldots&0&0\\
sin(\theta)&cos(\theta)&0&0&\ldots&0&0\\
0&0&cos(\theta)&-sin(\theta)&\ldots&0&0\\
0& 0& sin(\theta)&cos(\theta)&\ldots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&\ldots&cos(\theta)&-sin(\theta)\\
0& 0& 0& 0&\ldots&sin(\theta)&cos(\theta)\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Notice that $tr(A_{n}(\theta))=ncos(\theta)$. Since $-1\leq cos(\theta)\leq 1$ then $-n\leq tr(A_{n}(\theta))\leq n$.

If $n$ is odd. Consider the following matrix in $O_n(\mathbb{R})$:  $B_n(\theta,\pm)=\begin{pmatrix}A_{n-1}(\theta)& 0_{n-1\times 1}\\
0_{1\times n-1} & \pm 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Notice $-n+2=-(n-1)+1\leq tr(B_n(\theta,+))\leq (n-1)+1=n$ and $-n=-(n-1)-1\leq tr(B_n(\theta,-))\leq (n-1)-1=n-2$.

Thus, $T=[-n,n]$.